# Shared SQL Queries

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization, database-performance, sqlperformance

As far as I know, the same queries executed by different users over and over again are somehow stored (getting over the technical details) in the SGA memory, and by doing so the performance increases. My question is how the server can identify that the same query is executed by a different user without the need for a new hard parse since the original information about the query is stored in the PRIVATE SQL Area of the first user who made the call. I'm a little bit confused, to be honest. What I mean by that, is that you said that not every single query will be stored in the SHARED SQL Area, but a hash value, and my question is, how another session will know that the same query will be executed if the Private SQL Area of that another user does not know about the hash value of the same query in the SHARED SQL AREA.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is called a *cache*.  It is a common method to improve performance in many types of software systems.

Comment: The hash value of the same thing is the same, that's how hash values work.

Answer (score 0):

> since the original information about the query is stored in the PRIVATE SQL Area of the first user who made the call.

No, that's not correct. You need to read about [Library cache](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/memory-architecture.html#GUID-DE757E9C-3437-408A-8598-3EB4C8E2A3B0), [v$sqlarea](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/V-SQLAREA.html), [v$sql](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/V-SQL.html), [parent cursor, child cursor](https://books.google.de/books?id=hmYpj1OI0DoC&pg=PA193&lpg=PA193&dq=parent%20cursor%20oracle%20jonathan%20lewis&source=bl&ots=zeJ8aqWSPK&sig=ACfU3U2WtEObVzswp-3guR4JZGhm33P0GQ&hl=ru&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=parent%20cursor%20oracle%20jonathan%20lewis&f=false), SQL_ID and HASH_VALUE. Each cursor has parameter parsing_schema, so it depends in which schema it was parsed.

I would suggest 2 best books by Jonathan Lewis:

1. Oracle Core: Essential Internals for DBAs and Developers
2. Cost-Based Oracle Fundamentals

They cover almost all you may need to know about this topic.

Answer (score 0):

The text of your query is hashed, and the hash is used as a key to look up the query in a cache. The cache is, in fact, shared between connections.

So, your best bet is to make sure that each user issues the query with *precisely* the same query text. Use prepared statements for those queries, and supply parameter values for those statements.

That is, do NOT use statements with embedded constants like this:

```
SELECT first, middle, last FROM user WHERE user_id = 345 -- defeats cache!
```

Instead, use statements like this

```
SELECT first, middle, last FROM user WHERE user_id = ?
```

and supply values for the `?` parameters each time you run the query.

You didn't say which application programming language you use, and this business of using prepared statements varies from language to language.

Here's an [explanation for Java JDBC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html#overview_ps). And here's one for [php oci8](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-parse.php).